# Unable to install firebase-admin pip package for python django in Apple M1 chip

Tags: python, django, pip, firebase-admin, apple-m1

Unable to install firebase-admin in Apple M1 Chip System

System Configuration

```
System OS: macOS Bigsur(11.2.2) 
chip: Apple M1
python version: 3.9.2 
Pip Version: 20.0.1 
Djnago: 3.1.7
```

I create virtual env for my project using below steps

1. `install virtualenv using pip install virtualenv`
2. `virtualenv venv -p python3.x` (whichever you want)
3. `source /your_project/venv/bin/activate`
4. your `venv` will activate and then you can install requirements with the help of pip

After this i try to install firebase-admin **`pip install firebase-admin`** and i get error like below

```
File "/private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-build-env-aapo6r5y/normal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 48, in __init__
        import _cffi_backend as backend
    ImportError: dlopen(/private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-build-env-aapo6r5y/normal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-build-env-aapo6r5y/normal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-build-env-aapo6r5y/normal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture


 File "/private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-install-yurwgn0k/grpcio_2bb9c0d1fcb8462591aa5aa845bcb162/src/python/grpcio/_parallel_compile_patch.py", line 54, in _compile_single_file
      self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    File "/private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-install-yurwgn0k/grpcio_2bb9c0d1fcb8462591aa5aa845bcb162/src/python/grpcio/commands.py", line 250, in new_compile
      return old_compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs,
    File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Volumes/DATA-D/user/Project/project_name/Api/fitquid/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-install-yurwgn0k/grpcio_2bb9c0d1fcb8462591aa5aa845bcb162/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-install-yurwgn0k/grpcio_2bb9c0d1fcb8462591aa5aa845bcb162/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/2l/g855nfq11js0q9s9dc9ygk000000gn/T/pip-record-jmxgwm9r/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Volumes/DATA-D/Drashti/Project/Fitquid/Api/webapis/fitquid/venv/include/site/python3.9/grpcio Check the logs for full command output.
```

If try to insall **`pip install boto3`**,  **`pip install django`** etc. packages are working fine facing issue only with the firebase admin.

Comment: Is anyone has found a solution for this.? i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @PrashantJajal yes, just posted an answer, maybe it solves your problems

Answer (score 3):

Try running this command:

```
arch -arch x86_64 /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install firebase-admin
```

It seems that grpc is not providing support for M1 macs.

Here are related github issues:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/530
- https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/285
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082

Answer (score 0):

You can try this since this could be the issue:

First, upgrade pip

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then, update the setup tools:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

At last, install grpcio using :

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio==<version_number>
```

Comment: I have try this. but still same issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

None of these accepted answers seem to work, but the top answer here works for me.
[How can I install GRPCIO on an Apple M1 Silicon laptop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640705/how-can-i-install-grpcio-on-an-apple-m1-silicon-laptop)