# How can I install GRPCIO on an Apple M1 Silicon laptop?

Tags: pip, apple-m1, apple-silicon, direnv, grpcio

Every time I try to install a `pip` package with GRPCIO as a dependency inside a `.direnv` project I get a build failure due to my architecture being arm64. How can I work around this while waiting for the GRPCIO crew to release an update?

```
  Using cached grpcio-1.34.0.tar.gz (21.0 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/yoav/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/orca-g6p4a6cZ-py3.8/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jj/r3j0p91s2qgdpcpf5ptqr9qm0000gn/T/pip-install-n05vw0u0/grpcio_103d947f24954cde8b8a019b4c9f88fe/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jj/r3j0p91s2qgdpcpf5ptqr9qm0000gn/T/pip-install-n05vw0u0/grpcio_103d947f24954cde8b8a019b4c9f88fe/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/jj/r3j0p91s2qgdpcpf5ptqr9qm0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-z41yqiw6
         cwd: /private/var/folders/jj/r3j0p91s2qgdpcpf5ptqr9qm0000gn/T/pip-install-n05vw0u0/grpcio_103d947f24954cde8b8a019b4c9f88fe/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/jj/r3j0p91s2qgdpcpf5ptqr9qm0000gn/T/pip-install-n05vw0u0/grpcio_103d947f24954cde8b8a019b4c9f88fe/setup.py", line 359, in <module>
        if mac_target and (pkg_resources.parse_version(mac_target) <
      File "/Users/yoav/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/orca-g6p4a6cZ-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 113, in parse_version
        return packaging.version.Version(v)
      File "/Users/yoav/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/orca-g6p4a6cZ-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py", line 275, in __init__
        match = self._regex.search(version)
    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
    ASM Builds for BoringSSL currently not supported on: macosx-11-arm64
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What is this mysterious `requirements.txt` file that I seem to be missing?

Comment: But are the contents of this `requirements.txt` that the question is using?

Comment: Basically any dependency that requires `grpcio`, whether manually installed or present in a python project’s `requirements.txt` file would potentially have this arm-64 issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ASM+Builds+for+currently+not+supported+on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer need to do any of this. Things just work out the box now that the community support for Apple Silicon has caught up. Happy coding!

Comment: Can you show a working example? I can't make it work in Dockerfile using python 3.11.6-alpine and grpcio 1.59.2

Answer (score 72):

This seems to work well, do the following in the terminal

```
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1
```

And then install whatever package that you wanted to install, in my case I was trying to install firebase admin and I had to run the following

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

Or just run the below command if you just want to install grpcio

```
pip install grpcio
```

I found [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082) thread helpful to understand this issue in detail
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082

Comment: I needed a couple more variables to be set for it to work for me: `export CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include"` `export
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib"`

Comment: This didn't work for me afterall. The install passed but I ran into errors lateron. Much simpler: Install with conda. See my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/71241793/2745116

Comment: Worked for me "as is"

Comment: Worked for me "as is"

Comment: To add further context, when I used a `conda` environment, this worked for me "as is". When using a `venv` (i.e. via `python -m venv ...`), I also needed the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables provided by @Martim. YMMV so if this doesn't work as is, also try adding the additional flags.

Answer (score 25):

```
CFLAGS="-I /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1 GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

this works for me in my mac book pro M1 bigsur.
Thanks for the solution

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer, so other users can better understand it

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I also had to downgrade to Python 3.9.12.

Answer (score 17):

I found a solution that works taking from https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082 with more detail and the removal of certain unnecessary steps. Note that this only works on python version 3.9 as of this post date.

First, install `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv`.

```
brew install pyenv pyenv-virtualenv
```

Note that you might need to futz with the shell evaluation variable as simply adding `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` does not seem to work on the Apple M1 computers. Instead, run the following

```
pyenv init - >> .zshrc
pyenv virtualenv-init - >> .zshrc
```

Then go to your python project directory and create an `.envrc` and register it with `direnv`

```
echo 'layout pyenv 3.9.1' > .envrc
direnv allow
```

Next there install your `requirements.txt` via

```
GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1 GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
Collecting google-cloud-pubsub
  Using cached google_cloud_pubsub-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (210 kB)
Collecting proto-plus>=1.7.1
  Using cached proto_plus-1.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting grpc-google-iam-v1<0.13dev,>=0.12.3
  Using cached grpc-google-iam-v1-0.12.3.tar.gz (13 kB)
Collecting libcst>=0.3.10
  Using cached libcst-0.3.17-py3-none-any.whl (507 kB)
Collecting google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.22.2
  Using cached google_api_core-1.26.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.12.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.15.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
Collecting grpcio<2.0.0dev,>=1.0.0
  Using cached grpcio-1.36.1.tar.gz (21.5 MB)
Collecting googleapis-common-protos[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.5.2
  Using cached googleapis_common_protos-1.53.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (198 kB)
Collecting typing-inspect>=0.4.0
  Using cached typing_inspect-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 kB)
Processing /Users/rkmacmini/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/b7/a5/c4/504d913c2a55bb09c607541578ec5f844d1ff33467abe93ba5/PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4.2
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting six>=1.13.0
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.21.1
  Using cached google_auth-1.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (136 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in ./.direnv/python-3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.22.2->google-cloud-pubsub->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (49.2.1)
Collecting packaging>=14.3
  Using cached packaging-20.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0
  Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.3.0
  Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.6"
  Using cached rsa-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 153 kB 1.1 MB/s
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for grpc-google-iam-v1, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for grpcio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: six, protobuf, proto-plus, grpcio, googleapis-common-protos, grpc-google-iam-v1, mypy-extensions, typing-extensions, typing-inspect, pyyaml, libcst, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, cachetools, rsa, google-auth, pytz, pyparsing, packaging, idna, urllib3, certifi, chardet, requests, google-api-core, google-cloud-pubsub
    Running setup.py install for grpcio ... done
    Running setup.py install for grpc-google-iam-v1 ... done
Successfully installed cachetools-4.2.1 certifi-2020.12.5 chardet-4.0.0 google-api-core-1.26.1 google-auth-1.27.1 google-cloud-pubsub-2.3.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.53.0 grpc-google-iam-v1-0.12.3 grpcio-1.36.1 idna-2.10 libcst-0.3.17 mypy-extensions-0.4.3 packaging-20.9 proto-plus-1.17.0 protobuf-3.15.6 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pyparsing-2.4.7 pytz-2021.1 pyyaml-5.4.1 requests-2.25.1 rsa-4.7.2 six-1.15.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 typing-inspect-0.6.0 urllib3-1.26.4
```

NOTE: Some references say you need to point your CFLAGS, etc, at the brew installed openssl locations but that has not seemed necessary for me. If you have issue you can try the command with the CFLAGS enabled via

```
CFLAGS="-I /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1 GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Ok, so I did not need the CFLAGS version for my Apple M1 Macmini, but I did need it for my Apple M1 Macbook Pro... very strange.

Comment: Can confirm this solution works for Macbook Pro M1, first one that did after wasting about an hour. Thanks!

Comment: I had issues with `psycopg2` as well and had to change flags.
Although using latest command solved the issue. Thanks @reka18!

Comment: not worked even with CFLAGS flag in MacBook M1 pro!

Answer (score 14):

There's a much simpler and more reliable option:

```
pip uninstall grpcio
conda install grpcio
```

Comment: Actually it appears the normal `pip install grpcio` is working at this time

Comment: Ok, I was trying with an old version (Python 3.8.5), which failed in my conda environment, but `conda install grpcio` did work.

Comment: +1 After trying various solutions, the one that worked is "conda install grpcio" . Using conda-forge channel. There's apparently a lot of community work put into making packages play well with M1/arm64 architecture. Big thanks to you and all of them

Answer (score 10):

**Edit: Google now provides [official grpcio builds](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/#files) for Apple Silicon Macs, since version 1.51.3. Downloading an unofficial binary is no longer necessary.**

Unfortunately, Google does not provide `grpcio` wheels built for Apple Silicon Macs. As you see from [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082), users have come up with a variety of compiler flags to compile the library on M1, which don't always work.

Tired of these problems, I published the [grpcio-mac-arm-build](https://github.com/pietrodn/grpcio-mac-arm-build) repository, which contains a daily GitHub Actions job that compiles the latest stable `grpcio` and `grpcio-tools` releases for Apple Silicon. The compiled wheels for Python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, and 3.11 are available for download in the "Releases" page. Everything is open sourced and released with the same license of the `grpcio` library. This way, you don't need to compile the library at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the only solution that actually worked.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Just need to pip install your wheel files and it works!

Comment: The Edit update saved me - `pip install grpcio==1.51` removed the error

Comment: In case anyone runs into this when trying to install `grpcio` on Windows for Arm (e. g. in Parallels Desktop on an Apple Silicon Mac): Do not use the ARM64 Python installer! There is no pre-built binary for this configuration. You can use the 64-bit Intel Python instead and it will build just fine.

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts, I finally got it installed by running these commands:

```
xcode-select --install
brew install openssl re2

export LDFLAGS="-L$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew --prefix re2)/lib" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew --prefix re2)/include" 

GRPC_BUILD_WITH_BORING_SSL_ASM="" 
GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_RE2=true 
GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=true 
GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=true 

pip install grpcio
```

Taken from here: https://candid.technology/error-command-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1/

Comment: This would not work, because those GRPC_ shell vars would be visible for shell only, not for the pip command. One needs to either have them all in the same line, or prefix each GRPC_ var with `export ` so that they are exposed to all commands launched from that shell

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it work without changing any variable in my OS. This seems to be to do with python version issue.. i was using 3.7.12 failed. 3.8.12 failed. Finally, 3.10.2 got this package installed.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestion worked for me. What worked is below (assuming you have homebrew installed):

1. Run `brew install miniconda` (follow through with - `conda init "$(basename "${SHELL}")"`, as instructed.)
2. Either source your ~/.zshrc or kill your terminal and reopen.
3. Run `conda create --name myenv python=3.10`.
4. Run `conda activate myenv`.
5. Run `pip install grpcio`.

This has brew install the correct arm64 conda env in step 1, hence the rest is doable.

Answer (score 0):

The following settings worked for me,

Used https://asdf-vm.com/ to install and manage my python

Used https://direnv.net and created `$PWD/.envrc` with just one line

```
layout python
```

Made sure I installed latest python 3.9 using asdf

```bash
asdf plugin-add python 
asdf install python 3.9.15
```

Then did,

```bash
direnv allow .
```

That should create a python venv under `$PWD/.direnv`, then did

```bash
pip install -U pip wheel grpcio
```

**IMPORTANT**: Python versions other than 3.9.x did not work for my e.g. 3.10 fails with some `clang` issue