# Grpcio fails installation for Tensorflow 2.5 on arm64 Apple Silicon

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1, grpcio

I'm following the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ and having issues installing grpcio. When I try `python -m pip install tensorflow-macos` I get:

```
  AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp39', 'cp39', 'macosx_11_0_arm64')
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
```

The subsequent attempt also ends in an error:

```
Running setup.py clean for grpcio
Failed to build grpcio
Installing collected packages: grpcio, tensorflow-estimator, keras-nightly, flatbuffers
  Attempting uninstall: grpcio
    Found existing installation: grpcio 1.38.1
    Uninstalling grpcio-1.38.1:
      Successfully uninstalled grpcio-1.38.1
    Running setup.py install for grpcio ... error
```

The solutions given here: [How can I install GRPCIO on an Apple M1 Silicon laptop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640705/how-can-i-install-grpcio-on-an-apple-m1-silicon-laptop) have unfortunately not worked to me.

I am quite inexperienced with architecture/chip challenges, but it reads that the arm64 is currently not supported? If that is the case it is odd that it is included in the tensorflow_plugin steps. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Did adding `GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL`, `GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB` as environment variables not work?

Comment: Unfortunately not! I tried a few variations of this and it didn’t work. I did solve eventually using a community solution to 2.5, so will update this post.

Answer (score 4):

What helped me was:

```
GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1 GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1  python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to

1. Build `boringssl` manually ([github answer](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14573#issuecomment-433070661))
2. Use the flags while installing `grpcio` as explained in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69181343/1950328)
3. Upgrade numpy ([TypeError StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73177788/1950328))

##### Install

```bash
# The following are required to locally build boringssl
brew install go
brew install wget
brew install cmake
mkdir boringssl
cd boringssl
wget https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+archive/master.tar.gz
gunzip -c master.tar.gz | tar xopf -
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make

# Install `grpcio` with the right 
YCFLAGS="-I /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1 GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 pip install 'grpcio'
pip install tensorflow-macos

# If you see an error like below then upgrade numpy
#
# TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was () -> handle
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

##### Test

```bash
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```