# pip install tensorflow fails

Tags: tensorflow, pip, grpcio

I'm on MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.6, 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 processor. Python version: 2.7.

"pip install tensorflow" keeps failing for me. The error seems to be: "ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio".

I have tried resolving this by installing grpcio separately, which also runs into similar issues.

My attempted solution to run "pip install grpcio" after digging around did not work either:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio
```

At this point I'm pretty lost and have no idea how to resolve the issue. The full error message when running "pip install tensorflow" is too long for me to include here, but the partial message is as follows:

```
Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-install-sKNp6M/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-install-sKNp6M/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-wheel-ytpuzp
       cwd: /private/var/folders/hm/pt6_h7xs52z7_89jqr614q300000gn/T/pip-install-sKNp6M/grpcio/
  Complete output (1294 lines):
  ('ASM Builds for BoringSSL currently not supported on:', 'macosx-10.6-intel')
  Found cython-generated files...
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running build_project_metadata
  creating python_build
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_compression.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_channel.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_common.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_utilities.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_simple_stubs.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_interceptor.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_grpcio_metadata.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_server.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_runtime_protos.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_auth.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/_server_adaptations.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/interfaces.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/_metadata.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/utilities.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/implementations.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/beta
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/experimental
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/gevent.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/experimental
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/experimental
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/session_cache.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/experimental
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_base_server.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_metadata.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_typing.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_call.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_channel.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_base_channel.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_interceptor.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_server.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_base_call.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_utils.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/aio
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/_cython
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/_cython
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/experimental/aio
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/experimental/aio
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/callable_util.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/abandonment.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/stream.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/stream_util.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/future.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/logging_pool.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/foundation
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/common
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/common/style.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/common
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/common/cardinality.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/common
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/common/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/common
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/face/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/face/utilities.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/face/face.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/base/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/base/utilities.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/base/base.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc
  creating python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/_cython/_credentials
  copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_credentials/roots.pem -> python_build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/grpc/_cython/_credentials
  running build_ext
  Found cython-generated files...
  building 'grpc._cython.cygrpc' extension
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/python
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/python/grpcio
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/python/grpcio/grpc
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/census
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/health
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/priority
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/ring_hash
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_robin
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/weighted_target
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/xds
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/fake
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/google_c2p
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/sockaddr
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/xds
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/client_idle
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/deadline
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/fault_injection
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/http
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/http/client
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/http/message_compress
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/http/server
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/max_age
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/message_size
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/alpn
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/secure
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/secure
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/transport/inproc
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/admin
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/admin/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/annotations
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/accesslog
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/accesslog/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/bootstrap
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/bootstrap/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/cluster
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/cluster/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/core
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/core/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/endpoint
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/endpoint/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/listener
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/listener/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/metrics
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/metrics/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/overload
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/overload/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/rbac
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/rbac/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/route
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/route/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/trace
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/trace/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/clusters
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/clusters/aggregate
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/clusters/aggregate/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/common
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/common/fault
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/common/fault/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/fault
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/fault/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/router
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/router/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/network
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/transport_sockets
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/transport_sockets/tls
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/cluster
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/cluster/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/discovery
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/discovery/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/endpoint
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/endpoint/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/listener
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/listener/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/load_stats
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/load_stats/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/route
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/route/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/status
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/status/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/http
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/http/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/matcher
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/matcher/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/metadata
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/metadata/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/tracing
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/tracing/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/api
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/api/expr
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/api/expr/v1alpha1
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/protobuf
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/rpc
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/gcp
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/health
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/health/v1
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/lb
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/lb/v1
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/annotations
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/data
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/data/orca
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/data/orca/v1
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/type
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/type/v1
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/validate
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/xds
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/xds/core
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upb-generated/xds/core/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/admin
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/admin/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/annotations
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/accesslog
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/accesslog/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/bootstrap
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/bootstrap/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/cluster
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/cluster/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/core
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/core/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/endpoint
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/endpoint/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/listener
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/listener/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/metrics
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/metrics/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/overload
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/overload/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/route
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/route/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/trace
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/config/trace/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/clusters
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/clusters/aggregate
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/clusters/aggregate/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/common
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/common/fault
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/common/fault/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/fault
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/fault/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/router
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/http/router/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/network
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/transport_sockets
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/transport_sockets/tls
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/cluster
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/cluster/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/discovery
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/discovery/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/endpoint
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/endpoint/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/listener
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/listener/v3
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated/envoy/service/load_stats
  creating python_build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-
```

Comment: Do you realize that `pip3` is for whatever Python 3 version you have installed, and will have no effect on your Python 2 installation?

Comment: I've tried running it as ```pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio ``` which also did not solve the problem

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69181343/14290681) reference help to solve this issue?