# Install of python firebase-admin on Apple Silicon/M1 fails, grpico fails

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin, apple-m1, apple-silicon

The [python firebase admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python) isn't installing on Apple Silicon/M1. I've tried fixes in other posts here and on Github and they haven't worked. It's unclear to me if they work for anyone.

- [Github discussion](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/530)
- [related Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488831/unable-to-install-firebase-admin-pip-package-for-python-django-in-apple-m1-chip)

#### Installation Problem

The command `pip install firebase-admin` fails when it tries the setup script for the grpico package, which is a dependency of firebase.

I've tried the install with python 3.8.2, 3.9.4, and 3.9.5. All the versions failed. I've tried it inside a venv and globally, both failed.

My understanding of what's going on so far is:

1. grpico is a dependency of firebase-admin (version 5.0.0), so `pip install firebase-admin` will try to install grpico (version 1.38.0)
2. grpico is only compiled for x86, so upon trying the setup steps for grpico, something (pip maybe) starts running a bunch of `clang` commands, attempting to compile a version for arm.
3. Some part of the compile fails and spits out a crazy looking error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/brown/Developer/parse-tools/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] ...
```

#### My setup:

- Big Sur 11.4
- Python 3.9.5 (installed with homebrew) in a venv
- pip 21.1.3
- firebase-admin 5.0.0
- grpico 1.38.0

If someone has a working fix, please explain how it works. I'm not a huge fan of pasting random commands into the terminal without understanding what they do.

Comment: This is the bug report on grpcio project: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082. it is currently closed as fixed, but based on the comments it's still not working for many developers. You might want to try some of the workarounds discussed in that thread.

Comment: You could open terminal under Rosetta 2 emulation and see if that works for you. Solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477023/error-mach-o-but-wrong-architecture-after-installing-anaconda-on-mac#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Success - Simple but Mysterious

After reading every crazy guide on how to install grpcio, I was able to get it working with only two steps.

1. Set 2 environment variables to tell the setup script to do something different. Run the following commands in terminal:

`export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1`

`export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1`

What do these ENV vars do? Who knows. No one has bothered to explain or communicate around this issue at all. Classic.

2. Run `pip3 install firebase-admin`. This worked for me.

Comment: I commented on the bug report here what they do and that it worked for me back in January: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082#issuecomment-754565768.